# Differences between Get-AzPolicyState from Powershell and az policy state list form az cli

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

If i run the command

```
Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -Filter "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults'" # | where-object { $_.ComplianceState -eq "NonCompliant" }
```

I get an example response:

```
Timestamp                   : 22/04/2022 11:38:58
ResourceId                  : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/group_name/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/resouce_name
PolicyAssignmentId          : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.authorization/policyassignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicyDefinitionId          : /providers/microsoft.authorization/policydefinitions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
IsCompliant                 : False
SubscriptionId              : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
ResourceType                : Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults
ResourceLocation            : northeurope
ResourceGroup               : neu-rg-dev-bicep
ResourceTags                : tbd
PolicyAssignmentName        : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicyAssignmentOwner       : tbd
PolicyAssignmentScope       : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicyDefinitionName        : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicyDefinitionAction      : audit
PolicyDefinitionCategory    : tbd
PolicySetDefinitionId       : /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicySetDefinitionName     : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicySetDefinitionCategory : security center
ManagementGroupIds          : MSDN,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PolicyDefinitionReferenceId : keyvaultsshouldhavepurgeprotectionenabledmonitoringeffect
ComplianceState             : NonCompliant
AdditionalProperties        : {[complianceReasonCode, ]}
```

The correspondent command with Az cli is

```
az policy state list --filter "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults'" --query "[?complianceState=='NonCompliant']"
```

And the result:

```
  {
    "complianceReasonCode": "",
    "complianceState": "NonCompliant",
    "components": null,
    "effectiveParameters": "",
    "isCompliant": false,
    "managementGroupIds": "MSDN,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "odataContext": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/$metadata#latest/$entity",
    "odataId": null,
    "policyAssignmentId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.authorization/policyassignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policyAssignmentName": "a26a6876d6c14a45b79d547f",
    "policyAssignmentOwner": "tbd",
    "policyAssignmentParameters": "",
    "policyAssignmentScope": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policyAssignmentVersion": "",
    "policyDefinitionAction": "audit",
    "policyDefinitionCategory": "tbd",
    "policyDefinitionGroupNames": [
      "azure_security_benchmark_v3.0_dp-8"
    ],
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/microsoft.authorization/policydefinitions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policyDefinitionName": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "keyvaultsshouldhavepurgeprotectionenabledmonitoringeffect",
    "policyDefinitionVersion": "2.0.0",
    "policyEvaluationDetails": null,
    "policySetDefinitionCategory": "security center",
    "policySetDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policySetDefinitionName": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "policySetDefinitionOwner": "",
    "policySetDefinitionParameters": "",
    "policySetDefinitionVersion": "47.0.0",
    "resourceGroup": "group_name",
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/group_name/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/resource_name",
    "resourceLocation": "northeurope",
    "resourceTags": "tbd",
    "resourceType": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "subscriptionId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "timestamp": "2022-04-22T11:38:58.831865+00:00"
  }
```

As we can see, there is some information not on the powershell version. One of the properties with big impact is the `policyDefinitionGroupNames`.

Does anyone know a way to get that property using powershell?

Comment: The `AdditionalProperties` property is an array, have you inspected what's inside it?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes nothing useful. Its a key value, where the key is complianceReasonCode

Comment: Are you sure it's not `Get-AzPolicyStateSummary`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i looked into that command and it doesn't provide the information i need.

Comment: Try assigning the output to a variable, then using `$outVar | Get-Member` to list all the properties - the ones you need may be hidden that you can access explicitly.

Comment: My next suggestion is the same as Todd's, pipe to `Get-Member` to expose the properties that may be hiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know a way to get that property using powershell

As suggested by *@Todd* above, we have tried the same to get the property that you are looking for ,

Try to use the below `cmdlts`:

```
$outVar = Get-AzPolicyState -PolicyAssignmentName "xxxxxxxxx0" -Filter "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults'" # | where-object { $_.ComplianceState -eq "NonCompliant" }
```

[image]

To check if the property is available or not use `$outVar | Get-Member`

[image]

For more information please refer this [**`MS DOC| Get-AzPolicyState`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-7.4.0) & [**`Azure policy Definition structure`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure)