# Extracting azure policy report information using Get-AzPolicyState

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I have come across the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71970437/differences-between-get-azpolicystate-from-powershell-and-az-policy-state-list-f) and I have found it extremely useful as a first start.

**What am I trying to do ?**

when I look at Azure policies, I am trying to extract a report showing policy compliance.

For every policy, I am looking to extract information on the total number of non-compliant resources. There will be a one line entry for every non-compliant resource.

Extract the policy name i.e Key vaults should have deletion protection enabled, policy description, resource name for example key vault name, the resource group of the non-compliant resource, the subscription housing the resource.

**What have I done ?**

`Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId 'xxx' -Filter " ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and ResourceLocation ne 'eastus' and PolicyDefinitionReferenceId eq 'firewallshouldbeenabledonkeyvaultmonitoringeffect'"`

I played with an example below to filter it down using `PolicyDefinitionReferenceId`

The way the results was displayed wouldnt work for my report as It will need to be presented using excel or csv, when I tried to pipe the output to a table I get the error below. The azure subscription has a lot of policy items, so ideally I am trying to write the script such that it will export to csv or excel.

`Get-AzPolicyState : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' (InvalidOrderByColumnInQueryString: The orderby column 'table' is not a valid column name.)`

Comment: Use parenthesis like here :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-10.4.1#example-17-get-latest-policy-states-in-current-subscription-scope-with-filter-query-option

Answer (score 0):

> The way the results was displayed wouldnt work for my report as It will need to be presented using excel or csv, when I tried to pipe the output to a table I get the error below. The azure subscription has a lot of policy items, so ideally I am trying to write the script such that it will export to csv or excel.

Here is the updated script to fetch the `compliance` state in `Azure Policy` and send the same result to `Excel`.

```
$subscriptionId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$nonCompliantPolicies = Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Filter " ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and ResourceLocation ne 'eastus' and PolicyDefinitionReferenceId eq 'storageaccountshoulduseaprivatelinkconnectionmonitoringeffect'"

# Define a custom object for each non-compliant resource
$customObjects = $nonCompliantPolicies | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PolicyName = $_.PolicyDefinitionName
        ComplianceState = $_.ComplianceState
        ResourceType = $_.ResourceType
        ResourceGroup = $_.ResourceGroup
        SubscriptionId = $_. subscriptionId
        IsCompliant    = $_.IsCompliant 
        PolicyAssignmentScope =$_.PolicyAssignmentScope
    }
}

# Export the custom objects to a CSV file
$customObjects | Export-Csv -Path 'Azure_policy_compliance_report.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**Result:**

[image]

I have filtered the non-compliant policy states based on criteria. Then, for each non-compliant resources, created a custom object with the desired information, including **Policy name, ComplianceState, ResourceType, ResourceGroup, Subscription ID, and Is Compliant**, and I export these custom objects to a `CSV` file using `Export-Csv`.

**Excel Result:**[image]

Answer (score 0):

The InvalidOrderByColumnInQueryString error mentioned here is because of providing an invalid column name called 'table'. I was able to reproduce the error by running below command.

```
Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -Filter " ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and ResourceLocation ne 'eastus' and PolicyDefinitionReferenceId eq 'firewallshouldbeenabledonkeyvaultmonitoringeffect'" -OrderBy "table asc"
```

[image]

To resolve the error, provide a valid column name like Timestamp, PolicyAssignmentName, etc. For more information, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-10.4.1#-orderby) Azure document.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a way to export the output to csv, use Export-Csv cmdlet as shown below.

```
Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant'" | Select-Object PolicyDefinitionReferenceId, PolicyAssignmentName, PolicyDefinitionName, PolicySetDefinitionName, ResourceId, ResourceGroup, SubscriptionId | Export-Csv .\noncompliant_resources_output.csv
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions with regards to this topic.